# How can I combine expressions and predefined variables to get my build repository name as an uppercase string?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to get my build repository name as an uppercase string combining predefine variables and expressions on `Azure Devops` as follows:

```yaml
variables:
  repoNameUpper: $[upper(variables['Build.Repository.Name'])]

- script: |
    echo $(repoNameUpper)
```

Yet I get no output from it, what am I doing wrong here?

Yes, I know I could set a variable to achieve what I need using a bash script, yet I think it would not be so cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because the `Build.Repository.Name` is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task. in another words - is not known at plan compile time, **only** at job execution time.

[image]

You can find more info in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2721) GitHub issue.